# rmarkdown: pandoc: pdflatex not found

Tags: r, macos, pandoc, pdflatex, r-markdown

When I use the render{rmarkdown} to produce pdf file from .Rmd file on my Mac, an error message says

`pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed`

However when I check with

```
pdflatex -v
```

I got

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.10; using libpng 1.5.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

The pdflatex is installed in my machine.

Can anyone help to tell how can I tell R where to find the pdflatex?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you restart R after installing pdflatex?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[This answer on TexExchange might help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163849/mavericks-upgrade-screwed-up-my-pdflatex-command-not-found).

I found I was having issues with `pdflatex` "missing" after I upgraded to OS X Mavericks (e.g. when checking package builds in RStudio I was getting an `error tools::texi2pdf pdflatex missing` message).

1. Check that `/usr/texbin` exists.
   In terminal:

   ```
   cd /usr/texbin
   ```
2. If "No such file or directory" then you will need to create a symbolic link to your installation's texbin. Mine was in `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`
   In terminal:

   ```
   ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin /usr/texbin
   ```
3. In terminal, check the result of `echo $PATH`. Make sure that `/usr/texbin` is present. If it isn't present, then you need to add `/usr/texbin` to your `PATH` variable.

If you find yourself having to mess with the `PATH` variable, installing the latest version of [MacTex](http://tug.org/mactex/) might be a better solution.

**UPDATE:** OS X 10.11 El Capitan no longer allows writes to `/usr` so the latest version of MacTeX (2015) now writes a link to `/Library/TeX/texbin` instead of `/usr/texbin` on this system.

Comment: Section 8 of [this](http://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) very handy - you don't need to install a newer version of mactex

Comment: Might be useful to mention that a restart of R-Studio is needed after doing the symbolic link.

Answer (score 69):

For people using ubuntu who get stranded here a better option (because it is 1/5 the size) is to use:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

Which I found via https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128309

Comment: I required `texlive-latex-extra` package too.

Answer (score 25):

For those using Dunk's answer(For people using UBUNTU) who get a `Font <font> at <size> not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.` error, you also need:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-recommended
```

This does unfortunately expand the size of the texlive install considerably, but it is still about half the size of a `texlive-latex-extra` install.

Comment: You should probably suggest an edit to that answer, rather than write your comment as a new "answer".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I wouldn't be surprised if such an edit would actually be rejected. Regardless, it does expand on the solution to one of the problems faced.

Comment: You can shrink the footprint considerably by adding a `--no-install-recommends` parameter to `apt-get install`. For example, to get PDF rendering working with `rmarkdown`, I installed these which took ~300MB:

`apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-extra lmodern`

Answer (score 16):

This might help a bit, in case you don't have any Latex stuff installed yet.

**env: macOS Sierra**

1. from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307483/setting-up-basictex-homebrew

`brew cask install basictex`

2. Now you need to figure out where pdflatex is hiding...

```bash
(env) jluc@texbin$ pwd
/Library/TeX/texbin
(env) jluc@texbin$ ls | grep pdfla
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  wheel         6 13 Mar 10:36 pdflatex -> pdftex
(env) jluc@texbin$ ls /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  wheel  6 13 Mar 10:36 /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -> pdftex
```

**/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex** is what we need, you can't refer to the **pdftex** symlink and/or use `realpath` because `pandoc` specifically wants to see `pdflatex`

3. update your command line to point to the appropriate file.

`pandoc myfile.md --to=pdf -t latex -o myfile.pdf --latex-engine=/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Answer (score 15):

For people that get stranded here because the same error is showing up in their **Linux** distribution. Get pdflatex in e.g. Ubuntu by installing

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

its too much software, but needed for example by knitr (rmarkdown-pdf-compilation)

Answer (score 6):

As of 2020 (MacOS Catalina) JL Peyret's answer is the most applicable. It should be slightly updated, since the `--latex-engine` option in pandoc has been deprecated in favor of the new `--pdf-engine` option:

```
$ brew install --cask basictex
$ pandoc myfile.md --to=pdf -t latex -o myfile.pdf --pdf-engine=/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

Comment: Had to `brew install --cask basictex` because `Calling brew cask install is disabled! Use brew install [--cask] instead.`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as I wasn't able to knit pdf file & solved it by installing & running tinitex packages using those commands in the console -- not the terminal

```
> install.packages("tinytex")

> tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a possible solution that don't involve adding or installing more packages, you can try this:

On your console:

set PDFLATEX=C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex

set MAKEINDEX=C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\makeindex

This definition of environmental variables explicitly gives access to two of the executables necessary for generating a PDF for documentation.