# pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output

Tags: ubuntu, shiny, pandoc, shiny-server, pdflatex

I have installed my shiny server on Ubuntu. In addition I installed Texlive- full 2017 on the server as well. The problem is that downloading report from the shiny app on the server does not work (on my local computer is working !!!) the error is :

```
pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 41
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081991/rmarkdown-pandoc-pdflatex-not-found) steps as well to create the symbolic link, but nothing has changed !

my pdflatex is in this path :

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux
```

so I have create the symbolic linke like :

```
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux  /usr/texbin
```

and I have added the `usr/texbin` to the path.
Can anyone could tell me what I am missing here ?!!

Comment: Just installing `texlive-latex-base` should be sufficient. What's the output of `which pdflatex`? Is the `pdflatex` binary in `/usr/texbin`?

Answer (score 28):

`sudo apt install texlive-latex-base` seems to install `pdflatex`.

Comment: You also need two more packets or you will get some font related errors. `apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended`

Comment: in addition to `texlive-latex-recommended` and `texlive-fonts-recommended`, I also had to install `texlive-latex-extra` (on ubuntu)

Comment: These methods still work end-July 2023 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Install TexLive 2023 with pdflatex
I posted the full code to install pdflatex easily and working -> https://gist.github.com/rain1024/98dd5e2c6c8c28f9ea9d#gistcomment-4711349

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).